# What could I be?

Tags: riddle, word

> I'm easy to start
>
> But hard to finish
>
> You might spend time with me at night
>
> Or while you're at work
>
> Sometimes simple things turn into me
>
> And that is the worst

What am I?

A hint:

> Sometimes it's me and one person, but most notable examples of me include a group

Comment: Good answers so far but none are what I had in mind. I'll give a hint in a while if needed!

Comment: It feels like there aren't enough constraints, so people have to guess.

Comment: This needs to be narrowed down to prevent a large number of speculative answers

Comment: Considering this question has over a dozen answers, with most of them more or less fitting the question I'd say this question is clearly too broad. If you're looking for a specific answer, make a more specific riddle.

Comment: It's not sufficient that your intended answer fits all parts of the puzzle. If many answers could fit, then the puzzle is under-specified. A well-crafted puzzle will give enough information to rule in the intended solution while ruling out everything else. Also, potential solutions should be testable by referring to *the puzzle*, not by needing a response from the setter as to whether they're right or not. If the puzzle lacks enough specificity to make that determination, then it's probably *too broad*, and "hints" added to fix that aren't hints, they're a necessary part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try #2:

> A project

I'm easy to start

But hard to finish

> It's easy to start a project, but they are often time and effort intensive to finish.

You might spend time with me at night

Or while you're at work

> Though technically, you could do projects on the weekend, I assume that the list of places and times you spend time with them is not exhaustive.

Sometimes simple things turn into me

And that is the worst

> A simple task could turn into a full blown project.

Sometimes it's me and one person, but most notable examples of me include a group

> The largest and most notable projects involve teams of people.

Optional guess #3:

> A disagreement, for largely similar reasons to the other answers.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind! Sorry for it being too vague, I'll put more effort into future posts!

Comment: The question is on hold so I'm not sure how to mark this the answer...

Answer (score 11):

You could be

> An Addiction

I'm easy to start

But hard to finish

> Addictions are easy to start, but hard to finish.

You might spend time with me at night

Or while you're at work

> You could spend time contributing to addictions wherever you are.

Sometimes simple things turn into me

And that is the worst

> Anything could be an addiction, whether it be drugs, food, etc.

Comment: Good answer but not what I had in mind

Answer (score 10):

Is it

> a rumour

I'm easy to start

> Rumours can start anywhere with anyone

But hard to finish

> Sometimes rumours just don't die

You might spend time with me at night

Or while you're at work

> You can hear about it, think about it anytime

Sometimes simple things turn into me

And that is the worst

> Rumours start from nothing or from something completely innocent but some people put malice or just misinterpret/misunderstand things

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: The first two explanations work better than the last two.  But, overall, this answer is not bad.  Congratulations on your new badge!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're

> A distraction

I'm easy to start
But hard to finish

> It's very easy to get distracted, but often hard to stop being distracted and get back to work

You might spend time with me at night
Or while you're at work

> You can get distracted from any task - housework, actual work, even sleep!

Sometimes simple things turn into me
And that is the worst

> Like, for example, when you just go to check one specific email, and somehow end up on Puzzling.SE... or is that just me? ;)

Comment: Very good answer but not what I had in mind

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> A Book

I'm easy to start

> People start writing books all of the time.

But hard to finish

> People seldom finish the book they are writing.

You might spend time with me at night

> A common past time for amateur novelists is to write at night, when they have more time.

Or while you're at work

> A lot of authors will work on their book at work if they have downtime.

Sometimes simple things turn into me

> Many short stories have turned into books, and many simple sentences or prompts are crafted into a book.

Comment: Great answer but not what I had in mind

Comment: But this *is* an example of the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
Is it
```

> A thought?

```
I'm easy to start
```

> You can always quickly and easily start a thought.

```
But hard to finish
```

> Its hard to fully complete a thought.

```
You might spend time with me at night
```

> You think about thoughts at night.

```
Or while you're at work
```

> You think about thoughts at work too!

```
Sometimes simple things turn into me
```

> Simple ideas turn into thoughts.

```
And that is the worst
```

> Thoughts can be all-consuming.

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> Sleep?

I'm easy to start:

> It's always easy to fall asleep if you are tired

But hard to finish

> Having to get out of bed sucks

You might spend time with me at night or while you're at work

> You usually sleep at night and if you are tired or bored at work you can be sleepy too

Sometimes simple things turn into me and that is the worst

> E.G. reading

Answer (score 2):

> A problem?

I'm easy to start

> Anybody could start one quite easily

But hard to finish

> By definition - if it was easy to solve, it would simply be a task, not a problem

You might spend time with me at night

Or while you're at work

> Arguably more likely to occur at work, but could happen anywhere and any time.

Sometimes simple things turn into me

> Most anything could be turned into a problem if mismanaged.

And that is the worst

> Leaving something that could have been easily fixed to fester until it becomes a problem is indeed the worst.

Comment: This is coming close to what I have in mind

Comment: I don't have the points yet to comment on another's answer, but hagfy's answer was my second choice, so let's see how that goes.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking this, but not sure I can get everything to fit:

> A puzzle?

It fits mostly the same as other provided answers

I'm easy to start

> It's easy to start solving a puzzle

But hard to finish

> A lot of times you'll only get part way through it

You might spend time with me at night

> Puzzles you don't finish will tend to keep you thinking about them

Or while you're at work

> Even distracting you from your job (which I might be guilty of right now)

Sometimes simple things turn into me

> Not really sure, but puzzles can be made up of many simple ideas, ultimately resulting in a more complex puzzle?

And that is the worst

> Ever go for a walk with Professor Layton?  EVERYTHING IS A PUZZLE!

Conversely:

> You could be making the puzzle, which would have most of the same answers

Comment: Good answer but not what I had in mind. I added a hint, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> An argument

I'm easy to start

> It's easy to disagree with someone

But hard to finish

> No one wants to accept they are wrong

You might spend time with me at night

> Sometime you might not sleep because you had an argument with someone

Or while you're at work

> You can have an argument at work

Sometimes simple things turn into me

> Sometime a little detail can turn into an argument

And that is the worst

> It really is :(

With the hint

> Sometimes it's me and one person, but most notable examples of me include a group.
>  An argument can be with 1 person or in a group

Comment: It fits up until the hint. I guess you could argue with yourself, but not really.

Comment: Aww, for some reason I interpreted the 1st part as 2 people

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> Video game

I'm easy to start.

> It’s easy to start playing a game.

But hard to finish.

> It’s hard to stop playing a game.

You might spend time with me at night.

> Usually at night you will be free so you play game at night.

Or while you're at work.

> If you get stressed at work , can play games to relieve it.

Sometimes simple things turn into me.

> Video games can effect a person where he copies the hero in real life.

And that is the worst.

> It may effect the persons environment in doing so.

Hint

> Video game is usually played with a player or a group.

Comment: This is a special case  of [kraby15’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64848/19765#64850).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> A large pizza!

I'm easy to start

> Pizza is great and people love to start eating it

But hard to finish

> If it's large you can't finish it all at once

You might spend time with me at night

> Pizza is good for dinner

Or while you're at work

> Pizza is a common choice for work functions

Sometimes simple things turn into me

> You can make pizza from simple ingredients

And that is the worst

> Pizza made with sub-par ingredients isn't as good

Comment: Hard to finish a *<your answer>*? In what universe?

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> a dream? (1. dream as in the sleeping subconscious state or 2. dream as in future aspirations)

I'm easy to start

> 1. they start on their own usually, 2. it's easy and encouraged to have dream goals

But hard to finish

> 1. I've personally never "completed" a dream, 2. achieving ones dream goals is never easy and usually takes hard work

You might spend time with me at night

> 1. dream when you sleep, 2. sometimes you make plans or work towards your goals at night (after work)

Or while you're at work

> 1. day dreaming (awesome past time), 2. working towards your goals professionally

Sometimes simple things turn into me
And that is the worst

> 1. dreams about mundane things could be annoying? 2. sometimes seemingly simple things are the hardest to achieve: like dieting lol.

hint: Sometimes it's me and one person, but most notable examples of me include a group

> usually one person dreams, but often times, dreams involve other people (same with achieving goals etc)

Comment: This is basically the same as [user48609’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64848/19765#64884), but this one acknowledges the dual nature of the word that is used in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a

> A debate?

```
I'm easy to start
```

> It's easy to start a debate because our whole life is just debated about anything.

```
But hard to finish
```

> It's not easy to end a debate because each party of the debate will try to convince the other party about their ideas.

```
You might spend time with me at night
```

> A debate can happen anytime, but it's most likely to be at night while sitting with a friend or bunch of friends/family.

```
Or while you're at work
```

> While you're at work, you might be debating a "work idea" or any issue/problem/idea during lunch break.

```
Sometimes simple things turn into me
```

> Duh, we can debate over simple things. Do you sleep on your left side or right side? Which one is better? Let's go!

```
And that is the worst
```

> It is the worst because, at the end (which never ends actually), the issue is so simple that it didn't deserve all the time consumed to give arguments with or against.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Worrying?

I'm easy to start

> It's a common problem: it's way too easy to start worrying.

But hard to finish

> Just stop worrying! Yeah that often feels impossible.

You might spend time with me at night

> In bed at night is when people worry a lot.

Or while you're at work

> Work related stress is one of the main triggers.

Sometimes simple things turn into me

> 'Did I lock the door?' 'What did he mean by that?'

And that is the worst

> Yeah, worries indeed are the worst.

The hint: Sometimes it's me and one person, but most notable examples of me include a group

> The most notable worries are common ones such as 'Will company X go bankrupt.' or 'Will country Y start a war?'

Answer (score 1):

You could be

> Dream

Easy to start

> Dreaming is easy to start

But hard to finish

> But it's hard to reach your dream.

You might spend time with me at night

> We dream when we are sleeping.

Or while you're at work

> If there's nothing to do we dream at work.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  I fixed your spoiler tags - you need the characters >! (not just >) before each line.  :)

Comment: This answer feels ambiguous: the thing that you reference in your second explanation (‘‘hard to finish’’) and the thing that you reference in your third explanation (‘‘at night’’) are not really the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> A gambling game

```
I'm easy to start 
But hard to finish
```

> It is easy to start gambling but hard to stop.

```
You might spend time with me at night
or while you're at work
```

> Usually people gamble at night. Sometimes people gamble at work. Also people sometimes thinking about how to be better at some sorts of gambling games and so might spend time at work thinking about that.

```
Sometimes simple things turn into me and that is the worst
```

> well sometimes simple things turn into a gamble and that is the worst because usually this kind of gambles are bad for both sides (e.g. who can drink more, or daring someone to do something dangerous).

```
Sometimes it's me and one person, but most notable examples of me include a group
```

> it is possible to gamble with just one more person. But usually people gamble in groups.

Comment: How is a gambling game hard to finish?

Comment: @kraby15 edited. Must be my broken English that confuses you.

Comment: This is a special case  of [kraby15’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/64848/19765#64850).

Comment: @PeregrineRook You are partially right, though I believe my answer works better with the hint.